# OpenGL version is too old - but it is not?

Tags: opengl, cocos2d-x

I am trying to run a cocos2dx application, but I receive the following error.

> OpenGL version is too old
>
> OpenGL 1.5 or higher is required [your version is [null]]. Please
>   upgrade the driver of your video card.

My computer isnt really old, it's not the best computer but the opengl version says its 4.4, and my graphics card is AMD Radeon R5.

What do I have to do to get this to work?

---

### Display Devices

```
      Card name: AMD Radeon(TM) R5 Graphics
   Manufacturer: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
      Chip type: AMD Radeon Graphics Processor (0x9851)
       DAC type: Internal DAC(400MHz)
    Device Type: Full Device
     Device Key: Enum\PCI\VEN_1002&DEV_9851&SUBSYS_2268103C&REV_05
 Display Memory: 8652 MB


> Dedicated Memory: 1004 MB
>       Shared Memory: 7647 MB
>        Current Mode: 1366 x 768 (32 bit) (60Hz)
>         Driver Name: aticfx64.dll,aticfx64.dll,aticfx64.dll,amdxc64.dll,aticfx32,aticfx32,aticfx32,amdxc32,atiumd64.dll,atidxx64.dll,atidxx64.dll,atiumdag,atidxx32,atidxx32,atiumdva,atiumd6a.cap,atitmm64.dll
> Driver File Version: 8.17.0010.1404 (English)
>      Driver Version: 15.201.1101.0
>         DDI Version: 12
>      Feature Levels: 11.1,11.0,10.1,10.0,9.3,9.2,9.1
>        Driver Model: WDDM 2.0 Graphics Preemption: DMA  Compute Preemption: DMA
>            Miracast: Not Supported by Graphics driver Hybrid Graphics GPU: Not Supported
>      Power P-states: Not Supported   Driver Attributes: Final Retail    Driver Date/Size: 06/08/2015 00:00:00, 1494528 bytes
>         WHQL Logo'd: Yes
>     WHQL Date Stamp:    Device Identifier: {D7B71EE2-DB11-11CF-F076-6202BBC2C535}
>           Vendor ID: 0x1002
>           Device ID: 0x9851
>           SubSys ID: 0x2268103C
>         Revision ID: 0x0005  Driver Strong Name: oem44.inf:cb0ae414426d398f:ati2mtag_MullinsPA_Mobile:15.201.1101.0:pci\ven_1002&dev_9851&subsys_2268103c&rev_05
>      Rank Of Driver: 00D10000
>         Video Accel: ModeMPEG2_A ModeMPEG2_C ModeVC1_C ModeWMV9_C 
>         DXVA2 Modes: DXVA2_ModeMPEG2_VLD  DXVA2_ModeMPEG2_IDCT  DXVA2_ModeH264_VLD_NoFGT  DXVA2_ModeH264_VLD_Stereo_Progressive_NoFGT 
> DXVA2_ModeH264_VLD_Stereo_NoFGT  DXVA2_ModeVC1_VLD 
> DXVA2_ModeMPEG4pt2_VLD_AdvSimple_NoGMC  DXVA2_ModeVC1_IDCT 
> DXVA2_ModeWMV9_IDCT      Deinterlace Caps:
> {6E8329FF-B642-418B-BCF0-BCB6591E255F}: Format(In/Out)=(YUY2,YUY2)
> Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,1) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB
> VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY
> DeinterlaceTech_PixelAdaptive 
>                      {335AA36E-7884-43A4-9C91-7F87FAF3E37E}: Format(In/Out)=(YUY2,YUY2) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,0)
> Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY
> DeinterlaceTech_BOBVerticalStretch 
>                      {5A54A0C9-C7EC-4BD9-8EDE-F3C75DC4393B}: Format(In/Out)=(YUY2,YUY2) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,0)
> Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY 
>                      {6E8329FF-B642-418B-BCF0-BCB6591E255F}: Format(In/Out)=(UYVY,UYVY) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,1)
> Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY
> DeinterlaceTech_PixelAdaptive 
>                      {335AA36E-7884-43A4-9C91-7F87FAF3E37E}: Format(In/Out)=(UYVY,UYVY) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,0)
> Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY
> DeinterlaceTech_BOBVerticalStretch 
>                      {5A54A0C9-C7EC-4BD9-8EDE-F3C75DC4393B}: Format(In/Out)=(UYVY,UYVY) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,0)
> Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY 
>                      {5A54A0C9-C7EC-4BD9-8EDE-F3C75DC4393B}: Format(In/Out)=(YV12,0x32315659) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,0) Caps=
>                      {3C5323C1-6FB7-44F5-9081-056BF2EE449D}: Format(In/Out)=(NV12,0x3231564e) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,2)
> Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY
> DeinterlaceTech_PixelAdaptive 
>                      {552C0DAD-CCBC-420B-83C8-74943CF9F1A6}: Format(In/Out)=(NV12,0x3231564e) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,2)
> Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY
> DeinterlaceTech_PixelAdaptive 
>                      {6E8329FF-B642-418B-BCF0-BCB6591E255F}: Format(In/Out)=(NV12,0x3231564e) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,1)
> Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY
> DeinterlaceTech_PixelAdaptive 
>                      {335AA36E-7884-43A4-9C91-7F87FAF3E37E}: Format(In/Out)=(NV12,0x3231564e) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,0)
> Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY
> DeinterlaceTech_BOBVerticalStretch 
>                      {5A54A0C9-C7EC-4BD9-8EDE-F3C75DC4393B}: Format(In/Out)=(NV12,0x3231564e) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,0)
> Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY 
>                      {5A54A0C9-C7EC-4BD9-8EDE-F3C75DC4393B}: Format(In/Out)=(IMC1,UNKNOWN) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,0) Caps=
>                      {5A54A0C9-C7EC-4BD9-8EDE-F3C75DC4393B}: Format(In/Out)=(IMC2,UNKNOWN) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,0) Caps=
>                      {5A54A0C9-C7EC-4BD9-8EDE-F3C75DC4393B}: Format(In/Out)=(IMC3,UNKNOWN) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,0) Caps=
>                      {5A54A0C9-C7EC-4BD9-8EDE-F3C75DC4393B}: Format(In/Out)=(IMC4,UNKNOWN) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,0) Caps=
>                      {5A54A0C9-C7EC-4BD9-8EDE-F3C75DC4393B}: Format(In/Out)=(S340,UNKNOWN) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,0) Caps=
>                      {5A54A0C9-C7EC-4BD9-8EDE-F3C75DC4393B}: Format(In/Out)=(S342,UNKNOWN) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,0) Caps=
>        D3D9 Overlay: Not Supported
>             DXVA-HD: Not Supported
>        DDraw Status: Enabled
>          D3D Status: Enabled
>          AGP Status: Enabled

       MPO Caps: Not Supported
    MPO Stretch: Not Supported
MPO Media Hints: Not Supported
    MPO Formats: Not Supported
```

Comment: Is your graphics driver up to date?  Open a command prompt with `cmd` and then run `dxdiag`.  You can check your supported OpenGL version explicitly using varying tools.  Try [glview](http://www.realtech-vr.com/glview/).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the commend, glview says 4.4, and my driver is up to date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not much of an answer, but hopefully a helpful contribution:

The relevant error message is within [this file](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/blob/4d128a83f48f169ed8c041a0d433e0e37741c81c/cocos/platform/desktop/CCGLViewImpl-desktop.cpp) and implies that `glGetString(GL_VERSION)` is returning `NULL`. Which appears almost certainly to mean that you don't have a valid context, but the method involved — `GLViewImpl::initWithRect` — creates a window and validates success before reaching the version check. So something amiss in glfw looks more likely.

Are you able to step debug that file? If you're on Windows, are you sure you're not stumbling upon one of those edge cases where the accelerated driver isn't available to your program? The software driver is some prehistoric fixed-functionality implementation if memory serves.

Comment: Hi Tommy, appreciate your response. I am rather new to all this (in fact I am trying to run a colleagues application), so apologies for what maybe a silly question - but how would I debug that file? I am using a windows machine for this

Comment: Apologies; I haven't developed on Windows in a very long time so I'm a little clueless. If no other solution is forthcoming, and _for debugging purposes only_, try including cocos2dx in your project directly as source rather than linking to a built library. That should let you step debug just like any other part of your code.